# Store sessions on disk

Tags: node.js

I can't setup redis server because i'm on windows.

How can I store the sessions on disk so they will persist through node restarts?

Also, do I have to restart node everytime I modify a JS file for the changes to go through?

Btw, I'm already using express for node. Express uses the memorystore which means that sessions reset everytime node restarts.

Comment: why not install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and install redis in it?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions:

- https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/238 < actually Redis got a patch so it can be built on Windows, may not be perfect but works
- Make an account on https://redistogo.com/ , they provide a free database of 5Mb (which is ok if you just want to test out some things)
- You can use something like [connect-cookie-session](https://github.com/jpallen/connect-cookie-session), so that you store the session into the cookie (this is ok if you are just developing stuff and need to have durable sessions, and then use Redis into production)

`Also, do I have to restart node everytime I modify a JS file for the changes to go through?`

There are dedicated modules for that, one of the most popular being [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor). Read the docs on their official page, it's really easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I store the sessions on disk so they will persist through node
>   restarts?

To be honest I have only used redis as my session-store, but you could also try to use(also found using http://search.npmjs.org:

- [mongodb](http://mongodb.org) as your [session store](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo).
- [supermarket-cart](https://github.com/pkrumins/supermarket-cart) which I believe uses [supermarket](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-supermarket) under the covers.
- [connect-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=connect-fs): https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=connect-fs
- [connect-mysql-session](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=connect-mysql-session): A MySQL session store for node.js connect.
- [connect-cookie-session](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=connect-cookie-session): Connect middleware to allow you to store your sessions directly in the client's cookie.

> Also, do I have to restart node everytime I modify a JS file for the
>   changes to go through?

Will answer this later!

Comment: Connect-fs is the answer to the question. Although [session-file-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store) has at least few lines of a documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cloud-based redis like http://redis4you.com/